# The load and uninstal links are not functioning

Tags: bigcommerce

We are developing an app for bigcommerce using the oauth workflow.  The oauth works when i click on Instal when I click Instal from the Apps center.  However the load and uninstall links are not hitting the URLs specified.  We are still in Draft mode.